# Trouble inserting data in a SQLite databae

Tags: java, sqlite

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\users\\tim\\airline\\flightschedule.db");  
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO flights (flightID,departure,arrival)VALUES(?,?,?)");
            statement.setInt(1,5);
            statement.setString(2,"David");
            statement.setString(3,"Ortiz");
            statement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } finally {  
        try {  
            resultSet.close();  
            statement.close();  
            connection.close();  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the exception trace you're seeing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should call a different method.

First things first though:

Bad code (wide open to SQL Injection attack):

```
        statement = connection.createStatement();  
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
            "INSERT INTO flights 
               ('flightID','departure','arrival')
               VALUES('"+flightID+"','"+departure+"','"+arrival+"')");
```

Good code:

```
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO flights (flightID,departure,arrival)
               VALUES(?,?,?)");
        statement.setString(1,flightID);
        statement.setString(2,departure);
        statement.setString(3,arrival);
        statement.executeUpdate();

        // thanks to @lobster1234 for reminder!
        connection.commit();
```

Have you noticed I do executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery()? Because this is the cause of your trouble.

P.S. I also noticed that you pass flightID into the method as int, but insert it into database as a string. Not a good practice usually. Stick to one datatype. If ID is really a number, make it a number in the database and then call setInt(1,flightID); alternatively, pass it around as String too.

Comment: I do not see any exceptions, but the data is not being added into the database.

Comment: This is because the query only scans the DB. Frankly, I would expect SQLite to throw an exception on passing INSERT into query method, but I guess being lite means you can cut corners.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to executeUpdate() and used the prepared statements. It's still not successfully adding it to the db though.

Comment: OK, please update the code in the question to the one you have now. Please provide the table structure. Also, executeUpdate() returns an int -- number of updated/inserted records. Dump that one to console.

Comment: I opened a new class (minus the method) to test out the code and am now getting nullpointerexceptions at the 3 .close() lines. When I took them all out it worked fine and the data was inserted successfully... but I don't want to leave the connection open.

Comment: You get NPE because you do not use resultSet. Remove it at all. And add commit() as @lobster1234 suggested. Living in the world of declarative transaction demarcation, I forgot one need to do one :D

Answer (score 4):

Try calling [`connection.commit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29) after `executeUpdate()`. You can also get the value returned by `executeUpdate()` and make sure you get 1 and not 0, as this call returns the number of rows affected by the statement.

Comment: hehe... now I wonder if the original version with passing INSERT into query() would work too with SQLite after commit() added...

Comment: I hear ya! I've been spoilt by Spring-JDBC where you dont have to deal with the boilerplate code so much :)